# What does the layout of the interrupt enables in the "riscv,plic0" depend on?

Tags: assembly, riscv

I am trying to write platform independent helper functions in risc-v assembly language to use the platform level interrupt controller, labeled "riscv,plic0" in the device tree of the SiFive FU540-C000. The goal is to be able to disable and enable external interrupts.

In my following problem I am specifically referring to the SiFive FU540-C000, which is made up of one core featuring only machine mode and four cores featuring machine, supervisor and user mode.

In chapter 10.1 of the [SiFive FU540-C000 manual v1p0](https://static.dev.sifive.com/FU540-C000-v1.0.pdf), all hardware threads take up 0x100 bytes of the interrupt enables array, except hardware thread 0. The address range of hardware thread 0 is 0x80 bytes long.

Considering that hardware thread 0 belongs to the machine mode only core, I thought it might be related to the missing supervisor, user and potentially hypervisor modes. However, since the difference in length of the address ranges is 0x20 bytes, there is no reasonable pattern to distribute those three modes.

Why is the address range of hardware thread 0 in the interrupt enables exactly 0x20 bytes shorter than that of any other hardware thread?

**SOLVED**: I forgot that I am working with hex decimal numbers, in which case 0x80 is half of 0x100. Therefore, hardware thread 0 has half the address range of any other hardware thread, due to supporting only half the operating modes.

Comment: 0x100 - 0x80 = 0x80 in hex.  That's half the space.

Comment: Woops, I am dumb. Thanks Peter, this explains everything, haha.